# Read and write to .xlxs but save as new filename python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, file

Hi I am looking to rename a file after writing to it rather than using just writer.save()

I am using the code below

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
fn = r'C:\Users\j2jennings\OneDrive - LA TROBE UNIVERSITY\PhD Data\Part5_Output_Python_FinalPlayer_Name.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(fn, header=None)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl', keep_vba = True)
book = load_workbook(fn)
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False)

resultsQ1['OdChange'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=0, startrow=1)
resultsQ2['OdChange'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=1, startrow=1)
resultsQ3['OdChange'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=2, startrow=1)
resultsQ4['OdChange'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=3, startrow=1)
resultsQ1['60s'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=4, startrow=1)
resultsQ2['60s'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=5, startrow=1)
resultsQ3['60s'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=6, startrow=1)
resultsQ4['60s'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False, startcol=7, startrow=1)

writer.save()
```

What I want to do is change Player_Name from the initial file read and then save the output as a new file  for example Part5_Output_FinalBob_Jones.xlsx

I have looked at os.rename but not sure if that is the right function to use.

Comment: `pd` is undefined.

Comment: `pd.read_excel(fn,...` and `pd.ExcelWriter(fn`, are you just asking how to read and write to different files? just pass different file names?

Comment: @ScottHunter `import pandas as pd` so common even the pandas docs don't explicitly mention it after the very intro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataframe.to_excel() function wants the file path as the input. So you can specify what file path you want to save the output to:

input_file='...\Part5_Output_Python_FinalPlayer_Name.xlsx'
output_file='...\Part5_Output_Python_FinalBob_Jones.xlsx'

df_bob_jones.to_excel(output_file, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False)

This might be helpful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html